# Is /etc/environment supposed to be a symlink?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

According to [the docs on environment.d](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/environment.d.html#Description),

> For backwards compatibility, a symlink to /etc/environment is installed, so this file is also parsed.

But on my machine, Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, it's not a symlink it's a hard file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentations says a symlink **to** `/etc/environment` is installed, not that `/etc/environment` is itself a symlink.

`/usr/lib/environment.d/99-environment.conf` is a symlink to `/etc/environment`.